# JavaScript - Solution of an exercise does not work when using let instead of var

Tags: javascript, scope, var, let

I receive an error when replacing var with let. I suppose that it is related to their different scope but don't know how to modify the code so that it can work with let as well.

```
var array = [242, 682, 933];

for (var i = 0, sum = 0; i < array.length; sum += array[i++]){
  var b = array[i];
  var x = Math.floor(b/100) % 10;
  var y = Math.floor(b/10) % 10;
  var z = b%10;

  if (x+z!==y) {
    break;
  }
}

console.log (sum);
```

Comment: 924 expected result?

Comment: @HongyuWang Why?

Comment: declare `var sum` and inside `for` loop you can use `let`

Comment: @HongyuWang - that's not true. You definitely can use `let` in global scope. Just be careful b/c it has block scope everywhere else.

Comment: @Maxim Yes, the result is 924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `let` keyword limiting the variable scope more than `var` does.

check this : [let on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

If you want to access the `sum` outside of the loops block, you also have to declare it outside:

```
var array = [242, 682, 933];
let sum = 0; // <-- declaration in the highest scope

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
  let b = array[i];
  let x = Math.floor(b/100) % 10;
  let y = Math.floor(b/10) % 10;
  let z = b%10;

  if (x + z !== y) {
    break;
  }


  sum += array[i];
}

console.log (sum); // now you can access it here
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is that when you replace `var` in your for loop condition, then your variable `sum` would not be accessible from outside of the for loop so `console.log (sum);` would give you an error.